# Failed to build an ARM cross compiler with crosstool-ng

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, autotools, toolchain, crosstool-ng

I'm doing a lab from Free Electron to building a cross-compilation toolchain
But when I run the build command it fails shortly after downloading things...

My stuff : xubuntu 14.04.3  | crosstool-ng-1.19.0

When I run ./ct-ng build

```
[DEBUG]    Entering '/home/thibaut/felabs/sysdev/toolchain/crosstool-ng-1.19.0/.build/src/mpfr-2.4.2'
[DEBUG]    Running autoreconf
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'autoreconf' 
[ALL  ]    aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
[ERROR]    configure.in:294: error: automatic de-ANSI-fication support has been removed
[ALL  ]    /usr/share/aclocal-1.14/obsolete.m4:26: AM_C_PROTOTYPES is expanded from...
[ALL  ]    configure.in:294: the top level
[ALL  ]    autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
[ERROR]    aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
[ALL  ]    autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Extracting and patching toolchain components'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@257]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_mpfr_extract[scripts/build/companion_libs/110-mpfr.sh@37]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: do_companion_libs_extract[scripts/build/companion_libs.sh@22]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@600]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      'docs/B - Known issues.txt'
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  (elapsed: 0:03.97)
```

Comment: Sometimes you can get through the Autotools problems with `autorecon -f -i` (speaking from a lot of experience). Be sure Autotools and Libtool is installed (the dev versions). I have not seen the errors above, however. Maybe `autoupdate` will get rid of the de-ANSI-fication problem. You should probably kbuild with `V=1` for more verbosity.

Comment: Yes, I have Autotolols(Automake?) and libtool. From the doc I needed this packages installed : `sudo apt-get install autoconf automake libtool libexpat1-dev \
libncurses5-dev bison flex patch curl cvs texinfo \
build-essential subversion gawk python-dev gperf` I tried the autoreconf -f -i and autoupdate but nothing happend.  Idk if because I use the crosstool-ng1.19.0... Now there are 1.23.0 but this lab was for 1.19.0 so Idk if its good idea to upgrade to 1.23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION** : 
The problem was my version of mpfr... So to fixe that I config with `./-ct-ng menuconfig` , and I tell him to **rebuild this module**. It's was in the section **Companion libraries**.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like an incompatibility between version of `mpfr` used by `crosstool-ng` and your version of `autoconf`. I suggest to try a newer version of `crosstool-ng` (version 1.19 was released in 2013).

If you really need `crosstool-ng` 1.19, you can try to compile `autoconf` version from "Companion tools" (`EXPERIMENTAL` has to be set).

You can also try to install an another version of autoconf. I believe that Ubuntu 14.04 provides autoconf 2.13, 2.59 and 2.68. You can try them.

Comment: Yeah you right it was about the version of `mpfr`... So to fixe that  I config with `./-ct-ng menuconfig` , and I tell him to rebuild this module. It's was in the section **Companion libraries**.